# auto refresh of div in mvc3 ASP.Net not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ViewData.cshtml(Partial View)
This is partial View

```
<table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" width="100%" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th width="30%" align="center">Date</th>
            <th width="30%" align="center">Bill Amount</th>
            <th width="30%" align="center">PayNow</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            for (int i = @Model.bill.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
            <tr>
                <td width="30%" align="center">@Model.billdate[i]</td>
                <td width="30%" align="center">@Model.bill[i]</td>
                <td width="30%" align="center">                    
                    <a class="isDone" href="#" data-tododb-itemid="@Model.bill[i]">Paynow</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Index.cshtml(View)
This is my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("ShowScreen", "Home")';
        $('#dynamictabs').load(url)
    }, 9000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
<div class="dynamictabs">
    @Html.Partial("ShowScreen")
</div>
```

HomeController.cs(Controller)
This is home controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   fieldProcessor fp= new fieldProcessor();
   return View(fp);
}

public ActionResult ShowScreen()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

fieldProcessor.cs
My Model

```
public class fieldProcessor 
{
    public List<int> bill { get; set; }
    public List<string> billdate { get; set; }
}
```

Still Div is not getting refreshed.

Comment: try analyse network traffic in chrome or firebug. What error code generate on load url

Comment: `ViewData.cshtml(Partial View)` should be `ShowScreen.cshtml`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I tried your code. Seems to work. I add `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` reference and put a breakpoint into `ShowScreen` view.

Comment: yeh it is ShowScreen.cshtml.. even i checked keeping alert.. timer is running  but dive is not getting refreshed.. i am using <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I put an answer with some changes that you should do including controller, views and javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`$('#dynamictabs').load(url)`

Should be:

`$('.dynamictabs').load(url)`

...because your div has a **class** of dynamictabs, not an id.

Comment: You are right. When I tested it, I changed `<div class="dynamictabs">` for `<div id="dynamictabs">`. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Cool. Does the page have javascript errors? What behaviour are you seeing in the console or Fiddler? Is a request made at all and if so what's the response look like?

Comment: ...also you say the div isn't getting refreshed but it seems that your ShowScreen action method returns the view without passing a model to it, does it work if you visit `/home/showscreen` directly? Is it returning an error? If not, is the browser actually refreshing the div contents but the result is just the same every time?

Comment: I put a new answer explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

It will work with some code changes:

1) like greg84 said:

This line:

```
$('#dynamictabs').load(url)
```

Should be:

```
$('.dynamictabs').load(url)
```

2) Your controller should be like this:

```
  public ActionResult ShowScreen()
    {
        fieldProcessor fp = new fieldProcessor();
        /*Load fieldProcessor object*/

        return View(fp);
    }
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        fieldProcessor fp = new fieldProcessor();
        /*Load fieldProcessor object*/
        return View(fp);
    }
```

3) ShowScreen and Index should be strong typed views:

```
@model YourApp.Models.fieldProcessor
```

4) When your code call the partial view, you should pass the model, like this:

```
<div class="dynamictabs">
    @Html.Partial("ShowScreen",Model)
</div>
```